# how to store the mails into a array list object or database using spring integration

Tags: spring-integration, imap

i need to store the mails into a collection object or into database for mail processing. These are the following code can display the mails. anyone please guide to savethe mails to collection object(ArrayList) or database.

```
public void startMail(String user, String pw) {
        IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows
                .from(Mail.imapInboundAdapter(imapUrl(user, pw))
                        .javaMailProperties(p -> p
                            .put("mail.debug", "true")
                            .put("mail.imap.connectionpoolsize", "1")
                            .put("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.class)
                            .put("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", false)
                            .put("mail.store.protocol", "imaps"))
                        .simpleContent(true)

                    , c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(60000)))

                    .handle(System.out::println)
                    .get();
        this.flowContext.registration(flow).register();
      }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the actual problem?

Comment: I have created a Message Handler class and tried to store the mails into a list with the following codes and passed to the handle() . public class MessageProcess implements MessageHandler{

 @Override
 public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException

Comment: I need help on to store the received mails in a list object or in a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what and how yo are going to do with some collection but fort storing into database you need to use respective `JdbcMessageHandler` channel adapter in that `.handle()`.

See more info  in docs:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-outbound-channel-adapter

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-protocol-adapters